# Why was this question about Autohotkey script closed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

[Using AutoHotKey scripting language is it possible to swap Alt and Ctrl keys and also retain native AltTab key behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225842/using-autohotkey-scripting-language-is-it-possible-to-swap-alt-and-ctrl-keys-and)

I don't think the question should be closed as it is related to a language, is showing actual code and is asking properly.

Are [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey) related question not welcome on Stack Overflow? Does the fact that it is a simple question not deserve it to be on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You got a good explanation in a comment. It is not clear what your programming issue there is, or if there even is one. What makes `autohotkey` a programming related tool?

Comment: @Oded I think the explanation is completely void. How is code not related to software development? Ahk is a scripting language and the user is asking hot to change the code.

Comment: Meh, I'm not really sure if this counts as programming. Seems to be more of a Super User question

Comment: @Bart Please explain why? Is code even though it is simple not appropriate for SO?

Comment: @Armin You get into a bit of a grey area really. Similar issues happened around tools like Notepad++. Some say its questions should remain on SU, others say it's a development tool and is just fine on SO. I'm undecided I guess, leaning towards SU as the site for it.

Comment: @Bart I think ahk is far apart from notepad++. Just look at some larger programs. Ahk is based on c++ and you can do everything on it.

Comment: Programmers use Google, so questions about Google are on topic? Programmers eat food, so questions about waffles are on topic?

Answer (score 1):

Some small amount of scripting doesn't necessarily make it a programming issue, and the problem you're asking about definitely isn't programming related or unique to the programming profession. There *may* be some AHK questions that are on topic (I'm not familiar enough with it to know, though my inclination is that there aren't), but that doesn't make all of them so, and this seems to me to fall definitively into the off topic category.

Even if it were on topic, it's still not a great question. You've included a problem statement (what you're trying to do), and shown what you've tried; these are both positives. However, you haven't explained what's wrong with your current solution. Try thinking about these questions (then including the answers in your question): What is happening? What do you expect to happen? How do these two things differ?